# Как использовать dateFormat внутри showDatePickerDialog? Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, дата, datepicker

Попытался сделать `dateFormat` полем класса и использовать внутри `showDatePickerDialog` при смене даты, но использовать его пытаюсь вместо склеивания строки. Не получилось реализовать задуманное, надеюсь на вашу помощь. Прилагаю исходник без своего вмешательства:

```
class DataActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_data)

        val date = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy")
        val dateDefault = date.format(calendar.timeInMillis)
        editDate.setText(dateDefault)

        editDate.setOnClickListener {
            showDatePickerDialog()
        }
    }

    private fun showDatePickerDialog() {
        val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
            this@NewItemActivity,
            { _, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
                val selectedDate: String =
                    dayOfMonth.toString() + "." + (monthOfYear + 1) + "." + year
                editDate?.setText(selectedDate)
            },
            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        )
        datePickerDialog.datePicker.maxDate = calendar.timeInMillis
        datePickerDialog.show()
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
class DataActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val simpleDateFormat: DateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance()

    private val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_data)

        val date = simpleDateFormat
        val dateDefault = date.format(calendar.timeInMillis)
        editDate.setText(dateDefault)

        editDate.setOnClickListener {
            showDatePickerDialog()
        }
    }

    private fun showDatePickerDialog() {
        val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
            this@NewItemActivity,
            { _, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
                val selectedDate: String =
                    dayOfMonth.toString() + "." + (monthOfYear + 1) + "." + year
                editDate?.setText(selectedDate)
            },
            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        )
        datePickerDialog.datePicker.maxDate = calendar.timeInMillis
        datePickerDialog.show()
    }
}
```

Comment: "Не получилось реализовать задуманное" -- не очень понятно, с чем конретно у вас возникла проблема? [Отредактируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1306665/edit) вопрос, напишите чуть подробнее, что именно не получилось сделать.

Comment: @Vadik, я создал поле класса, но не получается его использовать вместо склеивания строки в DatePickerDialog.

Comment: Все равно не понимаю, в чем заключается проблема. У вас уже написан код по форматированию в onCreate(), точно такой же код можно написать и в другом месте (и попутно вынести форматтер в поле класса, как вы и говорите). У вас были какие-то свои попытки это сделать? Отразите их в вопросе, чтобы было ясно, на каком этапе вы остановились.

Comment: Отобразил собственные изменения, но не получается использовать внутри showDatePickerDialog при смене даты вместа склеивания строки.

Comment: Что вас останавливает написать `simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.timeInMillis)`, точно так же, как это сделано в onCreate?

Comment: Непонимание происходящего меня останавливает, могли бы вы показать, куда и как это прописать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, предлагаю завести еще одну проперти `maxDate`, чтобы зафиксировать максимальную возможную дату в календаре:

```kotlin
private val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
private val dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance()
private val maxDate = calendar.timeInMillis
```

Тогда инстанс `calendar` мы будем использовать для хранения текущей выбранной даты в календаре. Заиспользуем `maxDate` в методе onCreate:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data)
    editDate.setText(dateFormat.format(maxDate))
    editDate.setOnClickListener {
        showDatePickerDialog()
    }
}
```

И, наконец, поправим реализацию showDatePickerDialog, чтобы в коллбеке обновлялся календарь, форматировалась дата и выставлялся правильный `maxDate`:

```kotlin
private fun showDatePickerDialog() {
    val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
        this,
        { _, year, month, day ->
            calendar.set(year, month, day)
            editDate.setText(dateFormat.format(calendar.timeInMillis))
        },
        calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    )
    datePickerDialog.datePicker.maxDate = maxDate
    datePickerDialog.show()
}
```

Comment: Сделал всё как вы и показали, спасибо большое! Но получил ошибку в строках `dateFormat.format(maxDate)` и `dateFormat.format(calendar.timeInMillis)` (Type mismatch. Required: Editable? Found: String!). Научите как исправить?

Comment: Обновил ответ, нужно использовать `setText` вместо `text`.

Comment: Минутой ранее, всё же додумался до этого, но прописать не успел) Спасибо большое за помощь!